# Hwo to verify text in .dat file using Tbox Read/Create File or any other file operations

Tags: tosca

My file size gets increased whenever we run batch jobs. So it takes a lot of time to open the file manually. When i tried to do validations on the file, i'm getting this error. I tried copying the file from one format to another and it throws the same error. Your suggestions will be helpful.
Error: "Array dimensions exceeded supported range."

TIA